# Yii 2 ActiveDataProvider query with ->all() gives "Call to a member function andFilterWhere() on array" error

Tags: php, yii2

I need to pass `ActiveDataProvider` object to view and I can't understand why this:

```
$query = Incarico::find();

$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query,
]);
```

works, while this:

```
$query = Incarico::find()
    ->joinWith('allegatos')           
    ->all();

$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query,
]);
```

gives me the following error:

> Call to a member function andFilterWhere() on array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not apply `all()` to `$query` since `ActiveDataProvider` `query` property expects valid `ActiveQuery` instance while you are passing results of that query.

Comment: Thanks arogachev.. but what should I use if I need to get all records?

Comment: Just remove `all()` and apply needed conditions to `$query` after initializing `ActiveDataProvider`. For getting all records no other conditions are needed and `joinWith` is also redundant. You can configure sort instead (if it's needed).

Comment: mmhh.. ok. Now something is more clear.. But how I can get the related records if I'm not using `joinWith`?

Comment: With relations, for example `$model->allegatos`. If you want use eager loading instead of lazy loading, `$query = Incarico::find()->with('allegatos')` will be enough.

Comment: I'm sure that there's something that I can't understand: $model is not available in my index view... I need to build a view with a master table `incarico` and, through kartik gridview expandrow, open the related records, in table `allegato` that are related in this way: `public function getAllegatos() {return $this->hasMany(Allegato::className(), ['idIncarico' => 'id']);}`

Comment: If you have a different problem, you can create separate question for that. The current problem is solved.