# using sum() in yii2 along with group by a related field

Tags: yii2

I have a table bills which have 3 column - partyname, billdate, billamount. And there is another table parties which have columns partyname and district. Both are related with partyname. I can join them and display the data in gridview. What I want is to show the data as below

```
District    Billdate    Billamount
Kolkata 2016-03-02  20000
Malda   2016-03-02  30000
Jalpaiguri  2016-03-02  30000
```

The Billamount column is the sum(amount) of all the parties belong to the particular district. I've read [Yii2 - getting sum of a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26852453/yii2-getting-sum-of-a-column), [Yii 2 ActiveDataProvider query with ->all() gives "Call to a member function andFilterWhere() on array" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30257838/yii-2-activedataprovider-query-with-all-gives-call-to-a-member-function-and), [Yii2 Query does not return column sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34701451/yii2-query-does-not-return-column-sum?lq=1), [Yii2 - getting sum of a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26852453/yii2-getting-sum-of-a-column). But could not make it out. Please help.
My Search is

```
public function search($params)
    {
        $query = Bills::find();
        $query->joinWith(['parties']);

        //$command = Yii::$app->db->createCommand("SELECT sum(billamount) FROM bills");
        //$sum = $command->queryScalar();
        //echo $sum;
        //$sum = $query->sum('billamount');
        //echo $sum;
        // $sum = (new \yii\db\Query())->from('bills');
        // $sum = $sum->sum('billamount');
        // echo $sum;

        //$sum = $query->sum('billamount');
        //echo $sum;

        // add conditions that should always apply here

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extend you model with a var for sum alias

```
class YourModel extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

   public $my_sum;
   .....
```

then

```
 $query = Bills::find()->select('partyname, billdate, sum(billamount) as my_sum)';
 $query->joinWith(['parties']);
```

In your dataProvider you can then refer to the sum with `my_sum`